# Haml: How to include google font

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
%link{:href => "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" :rel => "stylesheet"}
```

gives me error. What should I use?

*Edit* sorry I wasn't specific. How do I properly include fonts using haml?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what error does it give. Also try adding `@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato';` to the beginning of your `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file.

Comment: The error is presumably caused by a missing comma: *...400,700"**,** :rel => ...* However, you could have also just used [`stylesheet_link_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag). If this is indeed your issue, I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all I would generally include that script in the `Application Layout`. When you generate a new application that is generally written in ERB which would make it quite easy to update and you would just put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700">` up at the top of the page between the `<head></head>` portion.

Otherwise if you are using HAML in that part of the app as well you would use `%link{href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"}`

Now then you just have to update the CSS to use that font in the portion of the application you wish to apply it.